# Access will not save because of system locate

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to save local Access db , my system locate is US English
I am tryign to save a db with Chinese characters.
Access gives me the following errors:

```
“microsoft Access cannot save the form or report, 
 because it displays characters from a language that cannot be saved in your current system locate, 
switch your system locate to the language in the form or report， and try again”
```

Do I really need to switch my locate for this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might just be able to add the language type you're trying to use to the database. In Access Options > Language

[image: Screenshot]

I've never used it with Chinese, so I am unsure how your results will be, but it should work out.

Comment: its already in the list, i would not be able to type if it was not there...